# Automatically add individual into ontology?

Tags: owl, ontology

Is there anyway to automatically add individuals into ontology? mean i'm developing an ontology related to document management system.. i want when user upload document, his/her name become individual and automatically added into the ontology. so is that possible? kindly help me.

Comment: ???? What about using a programming language + an API for OWL ontologies and write some code?

Comment: Too general. There are many ways of accomplishing this task, and which way to choose depends on constraints you have not mentioned. Programming language, any library you already know, any library you're required to use, any other features you need to support?

Comment: i'm using eclipse and using owl api .. i have written the code for ontology, in which i manually give values and that add them into the ontology, that alone run perfectly but when i use form to give value dynamically it gives me error.